# Email templating in django

Tags: django, email, django-templates, django-email

As we all know (or should), you can use Django's template system to render email bodies:

```
def email(email, subject, template, context):
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.template import loader, Context

    send_mail(subject, loader.get_template(template).render(Context(context)), 'from@domain.com', [email,])
```

This has one flaw in my mind: to edit the subject and content of an email, you have to edit both the view and the template. While I can justify giving admin users access to the templates, I'm not giving them access to the raw python!

What would be really cool is if you could specify blocks in the email and pull them out separately when you send the email:

```
{% block subject %}This is my subject{% endblock %}
{% block plaintext %}My body{% endblock%}
{% block html %}My HTML body{% endblock%}
```

But how would you do that? How would you go about rendering just one block at a time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is my third working iteration. It assuming you have an email template like so:

```
{% block subject %}{% endblock %}
{% block plain %}{% endblock %}
{% block html %}{% endblock %}
```

I've refactored to iterate the email sending over a list by default and there are utility methods for sending to a single email and `django.contrib.auth` `User`s (single and multiple). I'm covering perhaps more than I'll sensibly need but there you go.

I also might have gone over the top with Python-love.

```
def email_list(to_list, template_path, context_dict):
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.template import loader, Context

    nodes = dict((n.name, n) for n in loader.get_template(template_path).nodelist if n.__class__.__name__ == 'BlockNode')
    con = Context(context_dict)
    r = lambda n: nodes[n].render(con)

    for address in to_list:
        send_mail(r('subject'), r('plain'), 'from@domain.com', [address,])

def email(to, template_path, context_dict):
    return email_list([to,], template_path, context_dict)

def email_user(user, template_path, context_dict):
    return email_list([user.email,], template_path, context_dict)

def email_users(user_list, template_path, context_dict):
    return email_list([user.email for user in user_list], template_path, context_dict)
```

As ever, if you can improve on that, please do.

Comment: Well &*$# me. It works. Considering adding more fields to base to allow setting the from/from-name/reply-to settings.

Comment: Hah, I've been doing this with three different templates which is a PITA.  Definite +1 from me!

Comment: I like it. I'd always just used separate templates, which works fine, but this is a lot nicer to deal with (especially since you generally want the same context for all the templates anyway).

Comment: It doesn't support template inheritance at the moment - You need to specify each required block in your actual template. If anybody can figure that out, I'd appreciate it as that would make it much easier to set defaults in a base template... But maybe that's something for settings.py

Comment: I think if you use .get_nodes_by_type(loader_tags.BlockNode), instead of n.__class__.__name__ == 'BlockNode', then the template inheritance will work.

Comment: This ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17193 does pretty much the same thing.  Much more verbose, but also handles html, file attachments, and auto-generating plaintext.   (Here's the diff, with docs too... https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/17193/send_templated_mail.3.diff)  Might be worth bringing discussion on getting something along these lines into core up on the django-dev list.

Comment: This broke when I upgraded to Django 1.8. But it's an easy fix. Change `loader.get_template(template_path).nodelist` to `loader.get_template(template_path).template`. I found this solution via http://stackoverflow.com/a/29633563/250962

Comment: And now with Django 4.1 I was getting errors like "TypeError: 'BlockNode' object is not iterable". The solution this time was to change that above line from `loader.get_template(template_path).template` to `loader.get_template(template_path).template.nodelist`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two templates: one for the body and one for the subject.

Comment: Two files means two filenames for essentially the same thing. It's just a pain in the behind having to keep on top of that many templates.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get template inheritance to work using the `{% body %}` tags, so I switched to a template like this:

```
{% extends "base.txt" %}

{% if subject %}Subject{% endif %}
{% if body %}Email body{% endif %}
{% if html %}<p>HTML body</p>{% endif %}
```

Now we have to render the template three times, but the inheritance works properly.

```
c = Context(context, autoescape = False)
subject = render_to_string(template_name, {'subject': True}, c).strip()
body = render_to_string(template_name, {'body': True}, c).strip()
c = Context(context, autoescape = True)
html = render_to_string(template_name, {'html': True}, c).strip()
```

I also found it necessary to turn off autoescape when rendering the non-HTML text to avoid escaped text in the email