# Django: How can I get a block from a template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Suppose my template has in it something like `{% block subject %}my subject{% endblock %}` and I load this template with `tmpl = loader.get_template('mytemplate.html')`, how can I extract "my subject"?

Comment: Just out of pure curiosity, why on earth would you want to?

Comment: @Jack: Emails! I already have email templates, but I want to put the subject in there too.

Comment: I stumbled upon this question for the same reason, wanting to put my email subject, html, and plain version in one template. Someone's made a PIP package that does this for you (django-render-block).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Camilo's solution doesn't work when your template extends a base. I've modified it a bit to (hopefully) fix that problem:

```
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template.loader_tags import BlockNode, ExtendsNode

def _get_node(template, context=Context(), name='subject'):
    for node in template:
        if isinstance(node, BlockNode) and node.name == name:
            return node.render(context)
        elif isinstance(node, ExtendsNode):
            return _get_node(node.nodelist, context, name)
    raise Exception("Node '%s' could not be found in template." % name)
```

I'm really not sure if this is the right way to recursively iterate over all the nodes... but it works in my limited case.

Comment: Actually...just found an even better solution. Storing the email templates directly in the DB now. Makes em easier to edit, can store both HTML and Text versions in one entry (rather than 2 files), and I can add a field for subject as well.

Comment: I have taken this snippet to The Next Level, and made it work more broadly with recursive templates - https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email/blob/867ef61693d02a39ca902a30e66d5dd7dd941cda/templated_email/utils.py it breaks/loses information if you use {{block.super}} in inherited templates. Gladly accept fixes which will make it more complete

Answer (score 5):

```
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template.loader_tags import BlockNode

t = get_template('template.html')
for node in t:
    if isinstance(node, BlockNode) and node.name == 'subject':
        print node.render(Context())
```

This worked for me, using Django 1.1.1

Answer (score 5):

The proposed answers don't work since [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.get_template):

> Changed in Django 1.8: get_template() returns a backend-dependent
>   Template instead of a django.template.Template.

The new django.template.backends.django.Template isn't iterable, so a for loop gives the error:

> 'Template' object is not iterable.

A solution for those who use Django template system (based on @CamiloDíazRepka answer):

```
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template.loader_tags import BlockNode

t = get_template('template.html')
for node in t.template:
    if isinstance(node, BlockNode) and node.name == 'subject':
        print node.render(Context())
```

Comment: From Django 4.1 I think you'll need to change `t.template` to `t.template.nodelist`.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted this to make an include tag that gets only a section of the template in question. I'm sharing it here just in case someone else wanted it for the same reason.

Usage: {% include_block "template.html" "block_name" %}

```
@register.tag
def include_block(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, include_file, block_name = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag requires a two arguments" % (token.contents.split()[0]))

    #pass vars with stripped quotes 
    return IncludeBlockNode(include_file.replace('"', ''), block_name.replace('"', ''))

class IncludeBlockNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, include_file, block_name):
        self.include_file = include_file
        self.block_name = block_name

    def _get_node(self, template, context, name):
        '''
        taken originally from
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687173/django-how-can-i-get-a-block-from-a-template
        '''
        for node in template:
            if isinstance(node, BlockNode) and node.name == name:
                return node.nodelist.render(context)
            elif isinstance(node, ExtendsNode):
                return self._get_node(node.nodelist, context, name)

        raise Exception("Node '%s' could not be found in template." % name)

    def render(self, context):
        t = get_template(self.include_file)
        return self._get_node(t, context, self.block_name)
```